# Java Excel Pivot Table Field Conditional Formatting

Tags: java, excel, pivot, field

Please, could you advise, how to set up a Conditional formatting related to the MS Excel Pivot Table Data Field (not to the Excel sheet cell !).  The Excel pivot table is created via Java Apache Poi. I need a pure Java solution either via the Apache Poi library or via Spire.XLS or Aspose library. I prefer open source solution but if there is no other option I would welcome paid library if the solution works well. I failed searching this via Google Worldwide. Thank you very much. Miroslav

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Cells for Java can serve your needs. You may add conditional formattings to pivot table fields (row, column, data, etc.).

There are relevant APIs (method overloads, etc.) for the purpose:

- PivotFormatCondition.addDataAreaCondition(string fieldName) method
  which adds PivotTable conditional format limit in the data fields.
- PivotFormatCondition.addDataAreaCondition(PivotField dataField)
  method which adds PivotTable conditional format limit in the data
  fields.
- PivotFormatCondition.addRowAreaCondition(string fieldName) method
  which adds PivotTable conditional format range limit in the row
  fields.
- PivotFormatCondition.addRowAreaCondition(PivotField rowField) method
  which adds PivotTable conditional format range limit in the row
  fields.
- PivotFormatCondition.addColumnAreaCondition(string fieldName) method
  which adds PivotTable conditional format range limit in the column
  fields.
- PivotFormatCondition.addColumnAreaCondition(PivotField columnField)
  method which adds PivotTable conditional format range limit in the
  column fields.
- PivotFormatCondition.setConditionalAreas() method which sets
  conditional areas of PivotFormatCondition object.

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```java
        String filePath = "........";
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook(filePath + "Book1.xlsx");
        //Get the first pivot table in the first worksheet.
        PivotTable pivot = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getPivotTables().get(0);

        PivotFormatConditionCollection pfcs = pivot.getPivotFormatConditions();
        //clear all the current conditional formats (if required).
        pfcs.clear();
        workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getConditionalFormattings().clear();

        //Add new conditional formatting
        int pIndex = pfcs.add();
        PivotFormatCondition pfc = pfcs.get(pIndex);
        pfc.setScopeType(PivotConditionFormatScopeType.FIELD);

        //Sample code 1:
        pfc.addDataAreaCondition("myDataField1");
        pfc.addRowAreaCondition("myRowField");
        //Or
        //Sample code 2:
        // pfc.addDataAreaCondition(pivot.DataFields[2]);
        // pfc.addRowAreaCondition(pivot.RowFields[0]);

        pfc.setConditionalAreas();

        FormatConditionCollection fcc = pfc.getFormatConditions();
        int idx = fcc.addCondition(FormatConditionType.CELL_VALUE);
        FormatCondition fc = fcc.get(idx);
        fc.setFormula1("0.4");
        fc.setOperator(OperatorType.GREATER_OR_EQUAL);
        fc.getStyle().setBackgroundColor(com.aspose.cells.Color.getRed());

        workbook.save(filePath + "out.xlsx");
        workbook.save(filePath + "out.pdf");
```

You may also post your queries or comments in other [forums](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.